# pg_config in Postgresql 8.3.1

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to build Postgresql 8.3.1 from sources (later I need to run extension patch on the top of it). Nevertheless, the `src/tutorial` doesn't make

```
$make
make: pg_config: Command not found
make: *** No targets.  Stop.
```

I went to the `bin` directory of the installation and I found `pg_config.exe` there, I need help to make the configuration detect it.

I tried something like:

```
./configure --with-pg-config=path/pgsql/bin
 make
 make install
```

but it's still not working.

Thanks

Comment: Can you add more information about your build environment? OS, compiler, etc?

Comment: Just a side note: 8.3.1 is missing **years** of bugfixes. You should *at least* upgrade to the latest minor revision. And you have to plan your upgrade to a more recent version soon. 8.3 is going out of support in a few months!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure that `pg_config` is on the executable search path - the `PATH` environment variable - before running `configure`.

It appears that you're probably using MinGW with msys, in which case you can use the syntax Andrew proposed. The location of the PostgreSQL executables may be a bit odd on msys, though, as per [the documentation](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Posix_path_conversion). UNIX paths have colons in them, so they can't contain drive specifiers like `c:\`, so MinGW "mounts" the drive letters as root directory entries like `/c`. Thus, for `c:\Program Files\PostgreSQL 8.3\bin` you would use:

```
"/c/Program Files/PostgreSQL 8.3/bin/pg_config.exe"
```

Note the double quotes. Try running that as a command in msys, see what happens. If you got `pg_config` output not an error, add it to the `PATH` with:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/c/Program Files/PostgreSQL 8.3/bin"
```

If you're on Cygwin, then:

- That's not really an ideal environment, kind of half-windows, half-unix. Consider MinGW+msys, or compiling PostgreSQL natively using the Windows Platform SDK compiler and the Windows build scripts, as per [Installing from Source Code on Windows](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/install-windows.html) .
- Cygwin also mounts `C:\` as `/c/` so the path above should be just as valid for Cygwin.

This would've been a lot easier if you'd mentioned clearly:

- Your operating system
- Your compiler and toolset

Additionally, a_horse_with_no_name is quite right: Installing PostgreSQL 8.3.1 now is just nuts. At the absolute bare minimum you should be installing 8.3.21, the current version of the 8.3 series at time of writing. As per the [version policy](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) this is completely compatible with all 8.3.x versions. You should then begin urgent preparations to update to 9.2 (or 9.1 if you insist) before 8.3 goes end-of-life; again, see the version policy.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I'm on Windows 7, running Cygwin with gcc
updating the path has worked, now I have different error, it can't find a dll called "complex.dll"

Comment: @user1748199 New problem, new question.