# Compiling PostgreSQL 8.3.1 src/tutorial on Cygwin: "undefined reference to _SET_VARSIZE'"

Tags: postgresql

Following up on [my previous question about finding `pg_config`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12903619/pg-config-in-postgresql-8-3-1), I'm still having a hard time getting `/src/tutorial` sub-directory to compile.

I'm running cygwin on Windows 7. This is not an ideal environment, but I'm trying to get a PostgreSQL extension that was written in this version that uses a Windows based interface to work. I'll migrate to Linux and better PostgreSQL once I get it to run.

Back to the problem:

I got the following when I ran make on `/src/tutorial`. I didn't change anything in the directory.

```
$ make
dlltool --export-all --output-def complex.def complex.o
dllwrap -o complex.dll --def complex.def complex.o -L/usr/lib -lpostgres -L/usr/                                                                                                              lib -lpostgres
rm -f complex.def
gcc -O2 -pipe  -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Winline -Wdeclaration                                                                                                           -after-statement -Wendif-labels -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv  -I. -I/usr/include                                                                                                                  /postgresql/server -I/usr/include/postgresql/internal   -c -o funcs.o funcs.c
funcs.c:19:1: warning: ‘Pg_magic_func’ redeclared without dllimport attribute: p                                                                                                                 revious dllimport ignored
funcs.c: In function ‘copytext’:
funcs.c:74:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘SET_VARSIZE’
dlltool --export-all --output-def funcs.def funcs.o
dllwrap -o funcs.dll --def funcs.def funcs.o -L/usr/lib -lpostgres -L/usr/lib -l                                                                                                                 postgres
funcs.o:funcs.c:(.text+0xb6): undefined reference to `_SET_VARSIZE'
funcs.o:funcs.c:(.text+0x142): undefined reference to `_SET_VARSIZE'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status  
dllwrap: gcc exited with status 1
```

I have no clue what's the correct header file that need to be included in funcs.

This error occurs in an unpatched 8.3.1.

Thanks

**Edit**

I figured the above problem in my installation.
The Makefile under `/src/tutorial` runs

```
PG_CONFIG = pg_config
PGXS := $(shell $(PG_CONFIG) --pgxs)
```

and for my bad luck, there was another `pg_config` other than the one in my `installation-folder/bin`

So once I fixed that, everything under `/src/tutorial` built normally

Comment: `SET_VARSIZE` is a macro, not a function, so that error and the re-declaration of `Pg_magic_func` from `fmgr.h` both suggest that your patch has broken something. Try compiling a completely unmodified PostgreSQL 8.3.21 and see if that compiles fine. Only once you can compile an un-modified current patch release of 8.3.x fine, THEN try patching it with your changes. Using 8.3.1 is a huge waste of time, there's no sensible reason to use 8.3.1 instead of 8.3.21.

Comment: One note. This error also exists in the un-modified 8.3.1 version. I'll go ahead and try compiling 8.3.21

Comment: Good plan. There's no guarantee that it'll solve anything, but it's kind of silly not to use the latest bug fixes, and it's possible it could include some compatibility fixes in those 3+ years of bug fix and stability patches. If 8.3.21 won't build either I'd be suspecting that the tutorials just don't compile on Cygwin. I don't think the buildfarm compiles the tutorials, and very few people use Pg on Cygwin, so it's quite possible nobody would notice.

Comment: Seems reasonably likely that the 8.3 tutorials don't build under Cygwin, then. Darn. I'll raise it on the mailing list, but I doubt anyone's going to care too much about a soon-to-be-end-of-life'd version on a rarely used platform.

Comment: I wonder if there's a way to skip running the whole func part

Comment: Posted to pgsql-general: http://archives.postgresql.org/message-id/507CE47C.9050307@ringerc.id.au

Comment: "skip running the whole func part"? You could not build the tutorials, or if you only want to compile one part of the tutorial code, modify the Makefile . Otherwise I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: I meant modifying the Makefile so it doesn't compile funcs.sql which I think is causing the error.

Comment: `funcs.sql` doesn't get compiled, do you mean `funcs.c`? If so, remove `funcs` from the `MODULES=` directive. Honestly, I'm a bit confused about why it's so vital to build a the tutorial code in order to patch your PostgreSQL anyway.

Comment: Well, the extension codes I have contains some code under the /src/tutorial, and I wasn't sure whether building the tutorial is necessary or not. Anyway, I gave up on Cygwin, moved to Linux, had couple of libpq errors it took me a while to get what's going on and finally the whole code builds now. Thanks for your prompt help.

Comment: Could you add your fix as an answer so it can be upvoted or accepted?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, this was caused this time by an extra pg_config of the wrong version.  Chances are this was not the only aspect of the wrong version there as well.  Old header files being used would have been the proximal cause and pg_config would have directed to the old header files.

In general the right thing to do here is to locate all versions of two files and then determine which one is being used.  Those files are:

1. pg_config
2. postgres.h

Once this is done it should be a simple patter to determine which one to remove or move out of where it can be found by the scripts.